# Why Opencv provides RGB instead of BGR?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am using OpenCV - 3.4.9.31

I was trying to run a very basic code to read an image, but to my surprise, the output was in RGB colorspace instead of BGR.

```
import cv2
folder = 'C:/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/Images/'
picture = 'lena.png'
filename = folder + picture

Img = cv2.imread(filename)
cv2.imshow("Image", Img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Why do I see RGB image instead of BGR ?**

Comment: Why is this surprising?

Comment: The imshow() viewer converts the BGR file into RGB for display automatically.

Comment: Why would it be a surprise that OpenCV displays BGR images correctly?

Comment: the assertion in your title is wrong. `imread` reads **anything** and converts to **BGR**. `imshow` assumes **BGR** data and shows it **correctly**. you shouldn't have noticed any issue here.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert it to BGR, you can do this :

```
imgBGR = cv2.cvtColor(Img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.